# How can I pass in the contents of a null resource as a value in another resource block?

Tags: terraform

I have a null_resource  that creates an EC2 keypair and writes it to a .pem file in my current directory. Now I'm trying to pass the contents of that file to a parameter in parameter store.

Here's the **first** way I tried accomplishing that via the Terraform File function:

```
resource "null_resource" "generate_key_pair" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      aws ec2 create-key-pair \
        --profile ${var.profile} \
        --region ${var.aws_region} \
        --key-name "${var.resource_prefix}" \
        --key-type rsa \
        --key-format pem \
        --query "KeyMaterial" \
        --output text > ${var.resource_prefix}.pem
    EOF
  }
}
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "private_key" {
  name        = "/production/${var.resource_prefix}.pem"
  description = "Private key"
  type        = "SecureString"
  value       = file("${path.module}/${var.resource_prefix}.pem")

  depends_on = [
    null_resource.generate_key_pair
  ]
}
```

Which resulted in this error: `Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "./private.pem"; this function works only with files that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that │ resource.`

The **second** attempt was to access the attribute like-so:

```
resource "null_resource" "generate_key_pair" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      aws ec2 create-key-pair \
        --profile ${var.profile} \
        --region ${var.aws_region} \
        --key-name "${var.resource_prefix}" \
        --key-type rsa \
        --key-format pem \
        --query "KeyMaterial" \
        --output text > ${var.resource_prefix}.pem
    EOF
  }
}
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "private_key" {
  name        = "/production/${var.resource_prefix}.pem"
  description = "Private key"
  type        = "SecureString"
  value       = file("${path.module}/${var.resource_prefix}.pem")

  depends_on = [
    null_resource.generate_key_pair.provisioner["local-exec"]
  ]
}
```

Which gave this error: `References in depends_on must be to a whole object (resource, etc), not to an attribute of an object`

My **third** attempt was to ask chatGPT and this is the solution that still returned an error:

```
resource "null_resource" "generate_key_pair" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      aws ec2 create-key-pair \
        --profile ${var.profile} \
        --region ${var.aws_region} \
        --key-name "${var.resource_prefix}" \
        --key-type rsa \
        --key-format pem \
        --query "KeyMaterial" \
        --output text > ${var.resource_prefix}.pem
    EOF
  }
}

output "private_key_contents" {
  value = chomp(file("${path.module}/${var.resource_prefix}.pem"))

  depends_on = [
    null_resource.generate_key_pair
  ]
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "private_key" {
  name        = "/production/${var.resource_prefix}.pem"
  description = "Private key"
  type        = "SecureString"
  value       = "${output.private_key_contents}"

  depends_on = [
    null_resource.generate_key_pair
  ]
}
```

The error: `A managed resource "output" "private_key_contents" has not been declared in the root module`

I'm not sure what else to try, but the goal is just to have the contents of the keypair that gets created from my null resource (which correctly outputs to `${var.resource_prefix}.pem`) get passed in as a value for `value =` in my ssm_parameter resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt was close, however didnt work because `file` only works with file that already exist before Terraform runs. The [documentation states](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/file) in fact states:

> This function can be used only with files that already exist on disk at the beginning of a Terraform run. Functions do not participate in the dependency graph, so this function cannot be used with files that are generated dynamically during a Terraform operation. We do not recommend using dynamic local files in Terraform configurations, but in rare situations where this is necessary you can use the local_file data source to read files while respecting resource dependencies.

So instead, you can use the `local_file` data source:

```
resource "null_resource" "generate_key_pair" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      aws ec2 create-key-pair \
        --profile ${var.profile} \
        --region ${var.aws_region} \
        --key-name "${var.resource_prefix}" \
        --key-type rsa \
        --key-format pem \
        --query "KeyMaterial" \
        --output text > ${var.resource_prefix}.pem
    EOF
  }
}

data "local_file" "key" {
  filename = "${var.resource_prefix}.pem"
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.generate_key_pair
  ]
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "private_key" {
  name        = "/production/${var.resource_prefix}.pem"
  description = "Private key"
  type        = "SecureString"
  value       = data.local_file.key.content
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Provisioners in Terraform are for running arbitrary actions that stand alone, and are not intended for generating data to use elsewhere in the configuration. [Provisioners are also a last resort](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort), and so the documentation recommends using built-in provider functionality instead of abusing provisioners to take API actions outside of Terraform's purview.

The `hashicorp/aws` provider has built-in functionality for declaring EC2 key pairs, using [the `aws_key_pair` resource type](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort). Here's how you can use that to solve this problem without any need to hack around with temporary files on disk, in combination with [the `hashicorp/tls` provider's resource type for generating a private key](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key):

```
resource "tls_private_key" "example" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "example" {
  key_name   = var.resource_prefix
  public_key = tls_private_key.example.public_key_openssh
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "private_key" {
  name        = "/production/${var.resource_prefix}.pem"
  description = "Private key"
  type        = "SecureString"
  value       = tls_private_key.example.private_key_pem
}
```

In this case there are no temporary files required because the key material can flow directly from `tls_private_key.example` to the other two resources within the Terraform language runtime.